# Radiobutton not posting

Tags: html, kohana

I'm trying to post a radiobutton value, but I must have made a very dumb mistake. I'm using Kohana and Bootstrap as framework. This is my code;

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Geslacht</label>
<div class="controls">
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-heart"></i></span>
         <div class="btn-group geslacht" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
            <input type="button"  name="Geslacht" value="M" class="btn"/>
            <input type="button"  name="Geslacht" value="V" class="btn"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my controller

```
$check1->values(array(
'RelatieID'     => $relatie->pk(),
'AdresID'       => $check->pk(),
'Voornaam'      => $_POST['Voornaam'],
'Voorletters'   => $_POST['Voorletters'],
'Tussenvoegsels'=> $_POST['Tussenvoegsels'],  
'Achternaam'    => $_POST['Achternaam'],  
'Geslacht'      => $_POST['Geslacht'],
'Geboortedatum' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Geboortedatum']))
));
```

Comment: I can't see the form element in your HTML. How are you extracting the data from the input elements?

Comment: Where is your radio button

Comment: here is the radiobutton<div class="btn-group geslacht" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                        <input type="button"  name="Geslacht" value="M" class="btn"/>
                        <input type="button"  name="Geslacht" value="V" class="btn"/>
                     </div>

Comment: Those are buttons - not radio elements. `type="button" != type="radio"`

Answer (score 2):

if  you want to use radio button you should change

```
<input type="button"  name="Geslacht" value="M" class="btn"/>
<input type="button"  name="Geslacht" value="V" class="btn"/>
```

to:

```
<input type="radio"  name="Geslacht" value="M" class="btn"/>
<input type="radio"  name="Geslacht" value="V" class="btn"/>
```

[List of Input type](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.html#input)

**List of allowed/valid input type at http://dev.w3.org/ on 11/06/2013**

```
ⓘ input type=text
ⓘ input type=password
ⓘ input type=checkbox
ⓘ input type=radio
ⓘ input type=button
ⓘ input type=submit
ⓘ input type=reset
ⓘ input type=file
ⓘ input type=hidden
ⓘ input type=image
ⓘ input type=datetime 
ⓘ input type=datetime-local 
ⓘ input type=date 
ⓘ input type=month 
ⓘ input type=time 
ⓘ input type=week 
ⓘ input type=number 
ⓘ input type=range 
ⓘ input type=email 
ⓘ input type=url 
ⓘ input type=search 
ⓘ input type=tel 
ⓘ input type=color
```

Comment: Thanks worked, is there a way to hide the actual buttons and replace them with just text?

Comment: how the word says, `input` elements is to allow the user to input info, if you just want to show text then remove the input button and add the text inside a span or div

Comment: also input elements is to allow the user to send in the case of submit or button